# Matching elements with random id with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am new at Selenium. I am unable to catch the id value as the value keeps regenerating with every refresh 
`id=ClientAgreements_863f4ace-84fb-4dbb-bb8c-7d7835ceaec9__AgreementType`

```
<td>select</td>
<td>id=ClientAgreements_863f4ace-84fb-4dbb-bb8c-7d7835ceaec9__AgreementType</td>
<td>label=New</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

If ClientAgreements OR AgreementType text is fixed then you can try

```
//div[contains(@id,'ClientAgreements')]
//div[contains(@id,'AgreementType ')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `id` changes all the time, it's probably not a good idea to look for the element by its `id`. You need to come up with a location strategy that would be stable all the time.

As Rohit Ware said, if `ClientAgreements` and/or `AgreementType` in the id is enough, you can find it by XPath:

```
xpath=//*[contains(@id,'ClientAgreements')]
xpath=//*[contains(@id,'AgreementType')]
xpath=//*[contains(@id,'ClientAgreements') and contains(@id,'AgreementType')]
```

If not, look for other unique qualities of the element. Does have a `name` attribute or a unique class? Is it always the first (second, third?) element on the page with a particular attribute? Does it contain any specific text? Is it a child of an element you can find easily?

If you want us to help you, show us the HTML code of the element - you can add a few surrounding elements, too, if you think it's relevant. We will come up with a solution, but you'll have to look at CSS selectors and/or XPath either way so you'll be able to solve it yourself next time.

If you want to help yourself, Google [CSS Selectors tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20selectors%20tutorial) and [XPath tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=xpath%20tutorial) and take one.